# Merge list from different files into a super list

Tags: python, django

I have many different python files in a module. Each file has a list of its own say my_list = []

```
module
 __init__.py
 A.py # my_list = [1]
 B.py # my_list = [2]
 C.py # my_list = [3]
 D.py # my_list = [4]
 ..
```

I want to programmatically merge list in all the file and create a super_list [1, 2, 3, 4].

Here is what I have tried.

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module('module')
super_list = []
for file in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
  super_list += getattr(module, file).my_list
```

This seems to be working. The issue I have is that I need to add import A, B, C, D in `module.__init__.py`.

Is there a better way of doing same thing in python.

Comment: `super_list += importlib.import_module('module.' + file).my_list`

Comment: thanks @AshwiniChaudhary

Answer (score 0):

I would try, in `module.__init__` having a list of the module names in `__all__`, *this is the standard behavior to allow* `from module import *` and the bare code to import and extend the super_list, e.g.:

```
# module.__init__
import importlib
__all__ = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # List of what to import for from module import *
super_list = []
for sub in __all__:
    try:
       m = importlib.import_module(sub)
       super_list.extend(getattr(m, 'my_list'))
    except ImportError:
       pass # Ignore any import errors
__all__.append('super_list') # Add to the import * list
```

if you do not wish to allow `from module import *` then use a name other than `__all__` for your module list.

This puts the module specific behavior **in** the module where it belongs rather than in any code that happens to import it.  Potentially you could use `glob` to populate your `__all__` list but I wouldn't recommend it as good practice.

**The above is untested code**